# How can I save all of my Git stashes differences at once?

Tags: git, git-stash

Suppose I have multiple stashes in a local repository. When calling `git stash list` I get a list:

```
stash@{0}: work done on branch master
stash@{1}: work done on branch a001
stash@{2}: work done on branch a123
stash@{3}: work done on branch a233
stash@{4}: work done on branch a444
...
```

How could I save each of the diffs of each stash into separate files, all at once?

Comment: I do not know exactly one command but what about create new branch and then apply each stash one by one?

Comment: Are you looking for patch files, or directly applying changes?

Comment: @NikitaSalomatin I want to keep each diff of each stash in separate files

Comment: @kLabz patch files, not applying changes

Comment: That's what I thought, but @pedro-tavares was quicker :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
git stash list | sed 's/\//\_/g'|sed 's/ /\_/g' | awk -F ":" '{ system("git stash show -p " $1 " >> " $1$2$3 ".diff" ) }'
```

It will create the following files:

```
stash@{0}_work_done_on_branch_master.diff
stash@{1}_work_done_on_branch_a001.diff
stash@{2}_work_done_on_branch_a123.diff
stash@{3}_work_done_on_branch_a233.diff
stash@{4}_work_done_on_branch_a444.diff
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the Git documentation there is nothing that does this yet, the only thing you can do is repeat the command `git stash pop` until everything is popped out.

You can also apply the stashes on the order you want, or even select witch stash to appy at that moment using `git stash apply stash@{2}`.